# Error calling GetTermSets from Taxonomywebservice

Tags: web-services

Calling the following code:

```
int lcid = 1033;
string termSetIds = "<termSetIds><termSetId>8a10d231-6bc6-485e-b76f-c47b0566c200</termSetId></termSetIds>";
string version = "<versions><version>1</version></versions>";
string termStoreIds = "<termStoreIds><termStoreId>1990bbd6-d149-4ae6-88e9-b51fb5e30ac8</termStoreId></termStoreIds>";
string oldtimestamp = "<timeStamps><timeStamp>633992461437070000</timeStamp></timeStamps>";
string timestamp = string.Empty;

string result = taxonomy.GetTermSets(termStoreIds, termSetIds, lcid, oldtimestamp, version, out timestamp);
```

throws the following exception

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out that the problem is with the Term Store.  Creating a new term store and querying it's contents works fine. Now I have to work out how to find the problem entries in the production Term Store.